# How To set "Textbox" value in Gecko Browser?

Tags: c#, vb.net, browser, gecko

if its Source name="login" then how can i set User Name Value 
Source Html For userbname textbox:

Comment: <td class="Tbl_class" align="left">
<input class="Fclass" style="width: 500px;" name="login">
</td>

Answer (score 0):

Gecko is not that different with IE . try this way

```
{
    HtmlElementCollection elements = Geckowebbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    elements(1).SetAttribute("value", USERBOX.Text);
    elements(2).SetAttribute("value", PASSBOX.Text);
    elements(3).InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple in `GeckoBrowser`. Following two lines will set the `Textbox` value:

```
GeckoInputElement txtbox = new GeckoInputElement(geckobrowser1.Document.GetElementByName("login").DomObject);
txtbox.Value = "Your string";
```